# How to Give Padding to EditText box that exists in between Horizontal Dotted lines

Tags: android

How to Give Padding to EditText box that exists in between Horizontal Dotted lines..[image]

Here in below image Text i entered was only placed after vertical line of image..
But my text was entered from starting of dotted lines ..

I used code from this:
[Android - How to make all lines in an edittext underlined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361755/android-how-to-make-all-lines-in-an-edittext-underlined)

Comment: are you using relative layout?

Comment: No i just use View in my layout and append my class to that view like this:<View
 class="com.dharani.android.snailmail.PL.model.LinedEditText"     
 android:paddingLeft="20dip"  
 android:background="@color/transparent"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:lineSpacingExtra="20dip"
    android:minHeight="250dip"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:fadingEdge="vertical"     
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:capitalize="sentences"   
/>

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i got your question. Use `android:layout_marginLeft=""` tag for that. I will help you for sure.