# How to call onDraw from onChange of TextEdit

Tags: android

I am using the solution provided by the accepted answer in this question:

[Android - How to make all lines in an edittext underlined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361755/android-how-to-make-all-lines-in-an-edittext-underlined)

The problem is that the `onDraw()` method is only drawing lines when loading the view using the following count

```
int count = (height-paddingTop-paddingBottom) / lineHeight;
```

This will not draw lines when the user keeps writing until we exceeds the number of counted lines. I need to execute the `onDraw()` again or find a better brilliant way to draw a new line whenever the user starts a new one.

[image]

Comment: Did you try to simply call [`invalidate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29) (or `postInvalidate()`, if you happen to need to call if off the UI thread)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case is your View updated only when application is loading or when screen configuration changes. If you want to update the View at specific time you do not call [onDraw()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onDraw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29) directly, but you call method [View.invalidate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29). Then UI thread will redraw the view as soon as possible.