# Page line in editText in android

Tags: android, xml

how can appear pagelines in the editText in android , like picture ..?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with Default `EditText`, you need to find out any custom library to use this type of functionality with `EditText`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with custom `EditText` like the one below (copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10362098/3185707)).

```
public class LinedEditText extends EditText {
    private Paint mPaint = new Paint();

    public LinedEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initPaint();
    }

    public LinedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initPaint();
    }

    public LinedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initPaint();
    }

    private void initPaint() {
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setColor(0x80000000);
    }

    @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int left = getLeft();
        int right = getRight();
        int paddingTop = getPaddingTop();
        int paddingBottom = getPaddingBottom();
        int paddingLeft = getPaddingLeft();
        int paddingRight = getPaddingRight();
        int height = getHeight();
        int lineHeight = getLineHeight();
        int count = (height-paddingTop-paddingBottom) / lineHeight;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            int baseline = lineHeight * (i+1) + paddingTop;
            canvas.drawLine(left+paddingLeft, baseline, right-paddingRight, baseline, mPaint);
        }

        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```